# There is a way to make Axios return the data as default response?

Tags: node.js, express, axios

When we use Axios we always have to get the data from response. Like this:

```
const response = await Axios.get('/url')
const data = response.data
```

There is a way to make Axios return the data already? Like this:

```
const data = await Axios.get('/url')
```

We never used anything besides the data from the response.

Comment: “const { data } = await Axios.etc” might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a response interceptors

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
    // Any status code that lie within the range of 2xx cause this function to trigger
    // Do something with response data
    return response.data; // do like this
}, function (error) {
    // Any status codes that falls outside the range of 2xx cause this function to trigger
    // Do something with response error
    return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

what i normally do is create a js file called `interceptors.js`

```
import axios from 'axios';

export function registerInterceptors() {
  axios.interceptors.response.use(
    function (response) {
      // Any status code that lie within the range of 2xx cause this function to trigger
      // Do something with response data
      return response.data;
    },
    function (error) {
      // Any status codes that falls outside the range of 2xx cause this function to trigger
      // Do something with response error
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }
  );
}
```

in `./src/index.js`

```
import { registerInterceptors } from './path/to/interceptors';
registerInterceptors();//this will register the interceptors.
```

---

For a best practice don't use `axios` every where, just in case in the future if you want to migrate to a different `http` provider then you have to change everywhere it uses.

create a wrapper around axios and use that wrapper in your app

for ex:

create a js file called `http.js`

```
const execute = ({url, method, params, data}) => {
  return axios({
    url,
    method,//GET or POST
    data,
    params,
  });
}

const get = (url, params) => {
  return execute({
    url, method: 'GET', params
  })
}

const post = (url, data) => {
  return execute({
    url, method: 'POST', data
  })
}

export default {
  get,
  post,
};
```

and use it like

```
import http from './http';
....
http.get('url', {a:1, b:2})
```

so now you can customize all over the app, even changing the http provider is so simple.

Comment: Just make sure this interceptor is after anything that requires an actual response.

Comment: Great answer! Give us two options.
I love the tip to wrap the Axios. That way we don't need the interceptor and we could easily customize all the requests.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ES6 Destructing like this:

```
const { data } = await Axios.get('/url');
```

So you won't have write another line of code.